# improving formatting of 'annotated equations'

Tags: shading, annotate-equations

In one of the many (hundreds+) pages of lecture notes I have for several 'math-focused' classes, I often refer in words to pieces of an equation. This is easy to do on a blackboard -- use the words, point at or circle or some such the part of the equation you're referring to, dazzle students with your insight. In the written notes, I'd like to go beyond words, and have been fooling (a fair description) with the annotate-equation package to make it easier to refer to specific parts of an equation.

In the MWE (below), I have an example of an equation -- not particularly complicated, but convenient in that there are 2 distinct components on the RHS I'd like to 'direct the students attention to'. So, the annotate-equations package lets me highlight (by colour-shaded background, and other fancy bits) the two parts of the RHS.

But,

1\ I'd like the two 'shaded boxes' to be aligned at both the top and bottom. I understand that each box is 'scaled' relative to the height of various structural elements in that component of the equation, but...is there a way to use an absolute scale forcing each shaded box to be a specific height (i.e., let the user set the dimensions, rather than interpolate from the expression itself)? Apologies if this is in the docs -- either I missed it, or am not understanding it. Probably a bit of both.

2\ if not the annotate-equation package, anything else? I'm willing to bet there is a 'tikz-based' way to get there from here (which seems to often be the case). I'm not wed to annotate-equations (although it *is* pretty slick, and easy to implement), and am open to alternate suggestions/appproaches.

Here is the MWE -- you might need to compile twice to get things to 'look right' (same issue I run into occasionally with colouring bits of matrices using nicematrix).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,annotate-equations}

\begin{document}

Example of `colour-emphasis' to highlight parts of an equation:

\vspace{2cm}
\renewcommand{\eqnhighlightheight}{\vphantom{\frac{a}{b}}\mathstrut} %
\renewcommand{\eqnannotationfont}{\scriptsize\slshape}
\begin{equation*}
  \tikzmarknode{alph}{\tilde{\alpha}^{i}}
  \cong
  \eqnmarkbox[blue]{sumdiff}{\sum_{j,k}\Bigl(a_{j,k}^{i}-a_{j,k}^{*}\Bigr)}
  \eqnmarkbox[red]{sensbox}{\left.\frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial
  a_{j,k}}\right|_{~0.5\bigl(\textbf{A}^{i}+\textbf{A}^{*}\bigr)}}
\end{equation*}
\annotate[yshift=3em]{above}{sumdiff}{sum of differences in $a_{ij}$ elements}
\annotate[yshift=1em]{above}{sensbox}{mid-point sensitivity}
\annotate[yshift=1.5em]{left, label above}{alph}{treatment deviation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can try \renewcommand{\eqnhighlightheight}{\rule[-1cm]{0pt}{2cm}}

Comment: Perfect - that does exactly what I need. Even better, I understand what its doing, and why it works. ;-) Many thanks...